# order by id on firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

what i wanna do is sort out the data by id. I know i should use booksInstance.orderByChild("id"). i tried doing that and nothing has changed because i don't know where should i be using it in the code. here is how i am displaying the data.

```
private void getData(){
        firebaseDatabaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        // get reference to 'users' node
        booksInstance = firebaseDatabaseInstance.getReference("a3lamAlda3wa");
        books.clear();
        books.addAll(db.getAllA3());
        adapter = new BookGridAdapter(this, books);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (books.isEmpty()) {
            Constants.showLoadingDialog(this);
        }
        booksInstance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                storeData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
        booksInstance.orderByChild("id").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                BookData book = new BookData(

                        (String) dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(),
                        (String) dataSnapshot.child("book_name").getValue(),
                        (String)dataSnapshot.child("book_path").getValue(),
                        (String)dataSnapshot.child("book_path2").getValue(),
                        "",
                        (String)dataSnapshot.child("image_path").getValue(),
                        (String)dataSnapshot.child("image_path2").getValue(),
                        ""
                );
                db.insertA3(book);
                reloadData();
            }
        });
    }
       private void storeData(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        books.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot alert: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            BookData book = new BookData(
                    (String)alert.child("id").getValue(),
                    (String)alert.child("book_name").getValue(),
                    (String)alert.child("book_path").getValue(),
                    (String)alert.child("book_path2").getValue(),
                    "",
                    (String)alert.child("image_path").getValue(),
                    (String)alert.child("image_path2").getValue(),
                    ""
            );
            db.insertBook(book);
        }
        books.addAll(db.getAllBook());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This is how my database looks like

```
 "books" : [ null, {
        "book_name" : "book 1",
        "book_path" : "gs://appspot.com/books/1.pdf",
        "book_path2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
        "id" : "a-1",
        "image_path" : "gs://mostsharabdallah-c0c65.appspot.com",
        "image_path2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com"
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attaching your listener to the location of books, you attach it to the ordered query. So:

```
booksInstance.orderByChild("id").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
```

Out of curiosity: since your books have IDs already, why don't you simple store them under their ID as key?

Comment: i tried doing that but it is still not ordering it by id

Comment: What I posted is one of the problems with your code. There may be more, but this was definitely one. Update your question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck now](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also include the JSON that you are querying (as text). You can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is a Good Thing to do.

Comment: i have updated the question, and included JSON as text

Comment: Your code still attaches the listener to the unordered reference. `booksInstance.addChildEventListener(`.  That will result in children in an undefined order.

Comment: I changed booksInstance.addChildEventListener(  to  booksInstance.orderByChild("id").addChildEventListener( . but still not displaying it in order.

Comment: I quickly reproduced the data structure and ordering in JavaScript: http://jsbin.com/naqixuh/edit?js,console. If you follow the same logic in Android, it *will* give the same order.